# Add a column with the max value of the group

Tags: sql

I want to add an extra column, where the max values of each group (ID) will appear.
Here how the table looks like:

```
select ID, VALUE from mytable
```

> ID VALUE
>   1   4
>   1   1
>   1   7
>   2   2
>   2   5
>   3   7
>   3   3

Here is the result I want to get:

> ID VALUE   max_values
>   1   4   7
>   1   1   7
>   1   7   7
>   2   2   5
>   2   5   5
>   3   7   7
>   3   3   7

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your previous questions indicate that you are using SQL Server, in which case you can use [window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Value,
        MaxValue = MAX(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
FROM    mytable;
```

Based on your comment on another answer about first summing value, you may need to use a subquery to actually get this:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Date,
        Value,
        MaxValue = MAX(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
FROM    (   SELECT  ID, Date, Value = SUM(Value) 
            FROM    mytable
            GROUP BY ID, Date
        ) AS t;
```

Comment: Thank you, you'vebeen more than helpful

Comment: @user3531117 Better than say thank you in comment, mark it as accepted by clicking check sign under the number.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use GROUP BY in subselect.

```
select ID, VALUE, 
  (select MAX(VALUE) from mytable where ID = t.ID) as MaxValue
from mytable t
```

Comment: Don't you have the same value for all rows then?

Comment: `select ID, Date, sum (Value) from mytable` Date is month period and I want query to sum the values for each month. Then add a column that will reflect the max value for each ID. The problem is I don't want the query to execute the sum function twice that slows the process greatly

Comment: Don't add the comment to all answers, just edit your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a sub select and group by, then grab the MAX of this group:

```
select 
  ID, 
  VALUE, 
  (select MAX(VALUE) 
   from mytable 
   group by ID 
   having ID = t.ID
  ) as max_values
from mytable t
```

*Edit:*

I built a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8aa12/1/0), which shows that my solution works, but also VDohnal is correct and doesn't need the group by, so I'll upvote his answer.

Comment: The subselect should be enclosed in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query.

```
SELECT ID
    ,value
    ,(
        SELECT MAX(VALUE)
        FROM GetMaxValue gmv
        WHERE gmv.ID = gmv1.ID
        GROUP BY ID
        ) as max_value
FROM GetMaxValue gmv1
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: In my case I use a heavy sum function, and executing another table my not be that suitable. I wondered if there's a more easier way..

Comment: put your complete question, what are you looking for?

Comment: `select ID, Date, sum (Value) from mytable` Date is month period and I want query to sum the values for each month. Then add a column that will reflect the max value for each ID. The problem is I don't want the query to execute the sum function twice that slows the process greatly